# Find what's wrong with this function?

Tags: c, for-loop, pointers, copy, function-definition

I think there is no problem with this segment of code.

```
void copydata(uint8_t *datato, uint8_t *datafrom, int size)
{
    uint8_t *CurrentAddress = datafrom;
    uint8_t *StopAddress = datafrom + size;
    
    for(;CurrentAddress <= StopAddress;CurrentAddress++)
        *CurrentAddress = *datafrom++;

}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: My guess `<=` gives off-by-one.

Comment: `<= StopAddress` should probably be `< StopAddress`

Comment: it will never stop the loop because of the `=`

Comment: Why do you need this function? It looks identical to `memcpy(datato, datafrom, size)`

Comment: The interviewer asked this to find what wrong with this function.

Comment: Did you try to compile it? If you did you'd get a warning indicating what's wrong. Did you try to use the function? Did it do what it should?

Comment: Look at the To address........

Answer (score 0):

The function is wrong.

For starters it should be declared like

```
void copydata( uint8_t *datato, const uint8_t *datafrom, size_t size );
```

Or even better to declare it like

```
uint8_t * copydata( uint8_t *datato, const uint8_t *datafrom, size_t size );
```

Secondly the condition in this loop

```
for(;CurrentAddress <= StopAddress;CurrentAddress++)
```

shall look like

```
for( ; CurrentAddress < StopAddress; CurrentAddress++ )
```

or

```
for( ; CurrentAddress != StopAddress; CurrentAddress++ )
```

and at last you are trying to copy the array to itself

```
uint8_t *CurrentAddress = datafrom;
//...
*CurrentAddress = *datafrom++;
```

The function can look the following way

```
uint8_t * copydata( uint8_t *datato, const uint8_t *datafrom, size_t size )
{
    
    for ( const uint8_t *StopAddress = datafrom + size; datafrom != StopAddress; ++datafrom )
    {
        *datato++ = *datafrom;
    }

    return datato;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t * copydata( uint8_t *datato, const uint8_t *datafrom, size_t size )
{
    
    for ( const uint8_t *StopAddress = datafrom + size; datafrom != StopAddress; ++datafrom )
    {
        *datato++ = *datafrom;
    }

    return datato;
} 

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 10 };
    uint8_t a[N];
    uint8_t b[N / 2] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    uint8_t c[N / 2] = { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
    
    copydata( copydata( a, b, N / 2 ), c, N / 2 );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 3 4 5 5 4 3 2 1
```

Another approach is just to use the standard function `memcpy` declared in the header `<string.h>`. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

uint8_t * copydata( uint8_t *datato, const uint8_t *datafrom, size_t size )
{
    return ( uint8_t * )memcpy( datato, datafrom, size * ( sizeof( uint8_t ) ) ) + size;   
} 

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 10 };
    uint8_t a[N];
    uint8_t b[N / 2] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    uint8_t c[N / 2] = { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
    
    copydata( copydata( a, b, N / 2 ), c, N / 2 );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The progran output is the same as shown above.